# Python: Get array indexes of quartiles

Tags: python, numpy, percentile, quartile

I am using the following code to calculate the quartiles of a given data set:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import numpy as np

series = [1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,5,5,6,7,8]

p1 = 25
p2 = 50
p3 = 75

q1 = np.percentile(series,  p1)
q2 = np.percentile(series,  p2)
q3 = np.percentile(series,  p3)

print('percentile(' + str(p1) + '): ' + str(q1))
print('percentile(' + str(p2) + '): ' + str(q2))
print('percentile(' + str(p3) + '): ' + str(q3))
```

The percentile function returns the quartiles, however, I would also like to
get the indexes which it used to mark the bounderies of the quartiles. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Is the data always sorted? Or else, this question wouldn't make sense, unless I'm missing something. But if it *is* sorted, then you can directly calculate the index.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, the data is always sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Since the data is sorted, you could just use [numpy.searchsorted](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) to return the indices at which to insert the values to maintain sorted order. You can specify which 'side' to insert the values.

```
>>> np.searchsorted(series,q1)
1
>>> np.searchsorted(series,q1,side='right')
11
>>> np.searchsorted(series,q2)
1
>>> np.searchsorted(series,q3)
11
>>> np.searchsorted(series,q3,side='right')
13
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the data is always sorted (thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga), you can use the `rank` method from the Pandas [`Series`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rank.html) class. `rank()` takes several arguments. One of them is `pct`:

> pct : boolean, default False
>
> Computes percentage rank of data

There are different ways of calculating the percentage rank. These methods are controlled by the argument `method`:

> method : {‘average’, ‘min’, ‘max’, ‘first’, ‘dense’}

You need the method `"max"`:

> max: highest rank in group

Let's look at the output of the `rank()` method with these parameters:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

series = [1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,5,5,6,7,8]

S = pd.Series(series)
percentage_rank = S.rank(method="max", pct=True)
print(percentage_rank)
```

This gives you basically the percentile for every entry in the `Series`:

```
0     0.0625
1     0.6875
2     0.6875
3     0.6875
4     0.6875
5     0.6875
6     0.6875
7     0.6875
8     0.6875
9     0.6875
10    0.6875
11    0.8125
12    0.8125
13    0.8750
14    0.9375
15    1.0000
dtype: float64
```

In order to retrieve the index for the three percentiles, you look up the first element in the `Series` that has an equal or  higher percentage rank than the percentile you're interested in. The index of that element is the index that you need.

```py
index25 = S.index[percentage_rank >= 0.25][0]
index50 = S.index[percentage_rank >= 0.50][0]
index75 = S.index[percentage_rank >= 0.75][0]

print("25 percentile: index {}, value {}".format(index25, S[index25]))
print("50 percentile: index {}, value {}".format(index50, S[index50]))
print("75 percentile: index {}, value {}".format(index75, S[index75]))
```

This gives you the output:

```
25 percentile: index 1, value 2
50 percentile: index 1, value 2
75 percentile: index 11, value 5
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
series = [1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,5,5,6,7,8]
thresholds = [25,50,75]
output = pd.DataFrame([np.percentile(series,x) for x in thresholds], index = thresholds, columns = ['quartiles'])
output
```

By making it a dataframe, you can assign the index pretty easily.

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers the question... I'm not sure I understand the question though...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I assumed that the question was about structuring the output...