# Is there a way to get the index of a percentage of a cummulative sum from a sorted list?

Tags: python, list, numpy, percentage, cumulative-sum

Given a sorted list of real numbers, e.g.

```
x = range(20)
```

The task is to find the first index of the X% of the cumulative sum of the list, e.g.

```
def compute_cumpercent(lint, percent):
    break_point = sum(lint) * percent
    mass = 0
    for i, c in enumerate(lint):
        if mass > break_point:
            return i
        mass += c
```

To find the index of the number in the input list which is less than and closes to 25% of the cumulative sum,

```
>>> compute_cumpercent(x, 0.25)
11
```

Firstly, **is there a mathematical / name for such a function?**

Other than doing it with the simple loop as above, **is there a way to do the same with `numpy` or some `bisect` or otherwise?**

Assume that input list is always sorted.

Comment: Is this https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html

Comment: Nope it's different. Not percentile.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this maybe?

```
import numpy as np

x = range(20)
percent = 0.25

cumsum = np.cumsum(x)
break_point = cumsum[-1] * percent
np.argmax(cumsum >= break_point) + 1 # 11
```

Comment: Is there a name for this?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, which doesn't say much since I'm a Ruby web developer by trade ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Oh actually this is pretty tricky, try `percent=1.0` and you'll see a surprise.

Comment: @alvas If you use `>=` and not `>`, the answer will be 20 as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(20)
Percent = 25

CumSumArray = np.cumsum(x)
ValueToFind = CumSumArray[-1] * Percent / 100
Idx = np.argmax(CumSumArray > ValueToFind)[0] - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Following [this hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42958697/python-get-array-indexes-of-quartiles), one can use [searchsorted](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) to find an index of the element, that is close (lower) to a percentile/quantile value.

See example below:

```
import numpy as np

def find_index_left(xs, v):
   return np.searchsorted(xs, v, side='left') - 1

def find_index_quantile(xs, q):
    v = np.quantile(xs, q)
    return find_index_left(xs, v)

xs = [5, 10, 11, 15, 20]
assert np.quantile(xs, 0.9) == 18.0
assert find_index_left(xs, 18) == 3 # zero-based index for forth element
assert find_index_quantile(xs, 0.9) == 3
```

Note `xs` has to be sorted.